# Angular - why ViewRef can't inject to component

Tags: angular

I am trying to get `ViewRef` form component,here is the code:

```
import { Component,ViewRef } from '@angular/core'
@Component({
   selector: 'test-com',
   template: ` <div>just test</div>`
})
export class TestComponent{
   constructor(private _viewRef: ViewRef){}
}
```

when i run it,then error come out as follow:

> No Provider for ViewRef

but when i use `ViewContainerRef` instead,it's fine.

Do anybody tell me why! How Angular tell which Service can Inject, which not?

Answer (score 0):

This is as designed. See [#36235](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36235)